# jQuery autocomplete rows highlight on select

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

When the suggestion box appears and the user presses the Down key (or they move the mouse over one suggestion), I need the entire row to be highlighted. So far, when pressing the Down key, only the background of the hyperlink gets highlighted. I tried styling the ui-state-hover class, but that's only used on the anchor element. I can't figure out how to highlight the li element.

Here's my CSS so far:

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-autocomplete li:hover
{
    color:White;
    background:#96B202;
    outline:none;
}
```

**EDIT:**
To make it a bit more clear, the autocomplete generates its elements like so:

```
<ul>
<li><a>an element</a></li>
<li><a>another element</a></li>
</ul>
```

when the down key is pressed, the anchor element automatically gets the class ui-state-hover.

Comment: Could you get more detail because In the example you sent when you press down key or move the mouse over the element the row get highlighted. do you want to add more functionality?

Comment: No, it's not about functionality. Pressing the Down key already triggers the anchor element in the list item to get a new class, "ui-state-hover". I manage to make the anchor element's background the color I want. What I would like to do is make the entire list item that contains the anchor element the same color as the highlighted anchor element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being a beginner in CSS, I didn't see this earlier: I only had to make the anchor element's style `display:block`. In case anyone ever runs into this again.

Comment: This is wonderfully simple and I can't believe I missed it, but I must note that it doesn't work if you use arrow keys.

Comment: this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 29):

I had exactly the same problem, solved it by:

```
.ui-state-focus
{
    color:White;
    background:#96B202;
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: This is what im looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use events:

```js
yourElement.autocomplete({
        focus: function(event, ui) { console.log(var li = $(event.srcElement).parent()); },
});
```

`li` variable is what you need. You can change style or add class the way you like.

Comment: I tried using the focus event like this: focus: function (event, ui) {
$(".ui-autocomplete li a").parent().removeClass("ui-state-hover");
$(".ui-autocomplete li a.ui-state-hover").parent().addClass("ui-state-hover");} . The problem is that are cases where two elements get highlighted at the same time and it can be confusing to the user. I think it's because of when the focus event is called.

Comment: The idea is not only in focus event but in getting target element from  event object.
$(event.srcElement).parent()

Comment: Your solution has the same effect as my code. I did finally find the answer, it was only a matter of CSS. Thank you anyway !

Comment: I was CURIOUS what `event` was. Glad I know about `srcElement` now. Where in the world did you find out about the syntax of srcElement?

Comment: srcElement is part of JavaScript, not jQuery.You can read abobut it [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target) or in standards.